# Angular, how to use the build compression

Tags: angular, build, compression

In order to optimize the performance of my Angular application, I am trying to compress the Angular dist output by following this example:

https://dotnetthoughts.net/improve-angular-performance-with-gzip-compression-azure-blog-storage/

Basically, I installed this resource

```
npm install -g gzipper
```

And after, I run this command

```
ng build && gzipper c ./dist --include js,css,html --output-file-format [filename].[ext] ./dist-compressed/
```

But absolutely nothing happens: I just see a normal dist folder with uncompressed files. Maybe the example is not adapt to my Angular version; how can I create properly a compressed output of my app? I also tried other example but none worked.

Comment: What happens if you run `ng build`, then afterwards run `gzipper c ./dist --include js,css,html --output-file-format [filename].[ext] ./dist-compressed/`. There is no output at all?